# How to make outer div inherit height of inner, non-floated divs?

Tags: css, html, height, footer

I am trying to prevent my footer from overlapping onto the elements above it when browser window height decreases. I realized that it is because the other div `container` is not inheriting the height of inner divs, namely `#cart`.

**How can I make the outer div inherit height of the inner, non-floated divs?**

Here is the page where its happening:

http://fine-grain-2.myshopify.com/cart

See the screenshot below for an illustration:

How I want it to be:

[image]

How it is currently when the browser window height gets too short.

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="cart" class="cart clearfix">
</div>

<footer class="clearfix">
    <div class="additional-info"> Copyright © 2013 fine grain </div>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
.container:after {
    clear: both;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.container {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
}

.row:after, .clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after, .row:before, .row:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0;
}
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after, .row:before, .row:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0;
}
#cart {
    margin: 20px auto 0;
}

footer {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 0 1em;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.additional-info {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

Comment: Nice Site  in Container class set min-height:600px or 100% as you like then its working friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@novicePrgrmr change container class like this

```
.container {
    min-height: 100%;//min-height
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
}
```